# in_array Thinks Array is a Boolean?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I recently updated a WP site from PHP 7.4 to 8.1 and am now getting an error:

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, bool given

The offending line is:

```
if (in_array($cat->cat_ID, get_sub_field('category'))) {
```

The site uses ACF and the output of the category sub field is:

Array ( [0] => 1 )

So it appears that in_array now considers this a boolean? What's the best way to resolve?

Comment: ``get_sub_field`` would be returning a boolean value for sure. Do check it.

Comment: based on the [documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/) ```get_sub_field``` will return a boolean from 2022. If you want to check for categories you may use ```category_exists``` of native Wordpress. see the docs [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/category_exists/).

Comment: I'm confused. The 'category' sub field is of the ACF Taxonomy field type so that the user can select multiple categories (via checkboxes). So when I output the get_sub_field('category') field -- I get an array: Array ( [0] => 1 ). What changed between PHP 7.4 and 8.1?

Comment: Are you sure you got a value for this field? Probably it will return FALSE if no value is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend storing the sub field into a variable, which will allow you to test the type before performing operations on it.

```php
$category = get_sub_field( 'category' );

if ( is_array( $category ) && in_array( $cat->cat_ID, $category ) ) {
   ...
}
```

Definitely recommend checking the value of the sub field is set in the admin, and then also checking the meta value to confirm.

Comment: Ah. I had done that. But didn't include the is_array() function. Thanks, Caleb.